# fs.existsSync() always returning false when path has ../

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a line of code about which I have a problem. Basically, the purpose is to check if a file named `tech-bg.jpg` exists in the parent folder's sibling folder where the JS file is located.

This is the code:

```
fs.existsSync(path.join('..', config.ASSET_URL, 'images', config.BG_AUTH))
console.log(path.join('..', config.ASSET_URL, 'images', config.BG_AUTH))
```

Console Output:

```
../storage/images/tech-bg.jpg
```

Although the file exists, `fs.existsSync()` always returns `false`. I have tried removing the `path.join` and instead using string format, but it still returns `false`.

I also tried using `path.resolve`, which has the following console output:

```
C:\client_projects\tt\storage\images\tech-bg.jpg
```

Now it has the full path, but still no luck.

The directory structure:

```
root/
   .../storage
         ../images
            ./tech-bg.jpg
   ../router
        ./index.js
```

I am not very experienced in NodeJS Filesystem API, so somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong here. Thank You!

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. I have used a basic string format as well. But that doesn't work either. That value of the `path.join` is in the console output.

Comment: try `path.resolve`, which will give you the full path which is much easier to then debug if necessary.

Comment: Hi, I used the `path.resolve` which indeed returned the full path to the picture file, but still `fs.existsSync()` returns false

Comment: That means your path is incorrect.  Can't really help you here since I can't see your filesystem.  Verify that the path it gives you is 100% correct, and that you have the `..` in the right place

Comment: I have edited the question and have added my filesystem, and I have verified that the file is there.

Comment: Have you tried using `${__dirname}`.

Comment: If the file were there, it wouldn't return false for absolute path. This means that absolute path is wrong. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem - a repo, etc.

Comment: Check for whitespace at the end of the pathname generated by your program (an easy way to do that is to change that first `console.log` call to `console.log(path.join(...) + '|')`.  If that looks OK then check for whitespace at the end of the name of the actual file in the filesystem.  Also check that the file does not have a double suffix (as in `tech-bg.jpg.jpg` or even `tech-bg.jpg.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

```
root/
   .../storage
         **../images**
            ./tech-bg.jpg
   ../router
        ./index.js
```

The main problem is with  "../images" as your images folder is not an immediate child of storage.

Here is code works fine here-

**router=>index.js**

```
const fs=require("fs");
var isExists=fs.existsSync("../storage/images/tech-bg.jpg");
console.log(isExists);
```

**Below is directory system and node output-**

[image: Node output-]

[image: Directory system-]